# Web Services Parser error ASP.Net ASP.Classic

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp-classic

Can someone help me with this error? I have a web service error and this error always occurs.

> An error occured during the parsing of a resource required to service
>   this request. Please review the following specific parse error details
>   and modify your source file appropriately.

Parse Error Message:

> Could not create type 'Service1.WebApp.InvoiceServiceService'

Comment: Share some code which is causing error. Is it is Web Service or WCF service? It is runtime error or compiletime error?

Comment: It is a runtime error and Web service.